# Django/Python: Adding incrementing numbers to bulk of usernames

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am creating a game where I have a player list, and when a game is created a list of players (users) is generated. The function below creates a player with random usernames, for example "Player_0tt".

I wish to instead of having random ascii_lowercase + digits, to increment each user by 1. So the first user is called Player_1, Player_2..etc. I will be adding the game ID to the username to make each game users unique but for now I am trying to get the 1, 2, 3...behind my usernames.

Should I make a new function that increments, or is there a smarter way to do this?

**Create random username**

```
def generate_username(length=3, chars=ascii_lowercase + digits, split=7, delimiter='_'):
    username = 'Player' + ''.join([choice(chars) for i in range(length)])

    if split:
        username = delimiter.join([username[start:start + split] for start in range(0, len(username), split)])

    try:
        User.objects.get(username=username)
        return generate_random_username(length=length, chars=chars, split=split, delimiter=delimiter)
    except User.DoesNotExist:

        return username
```

Comment: you can use regex to find latest player with username matching given delimiter, length and chars; let's say this gave us Player_m, you can name the new player Player_m+1 and if it did not return anything (there wasn't any player matching those parameters) then name the new player as Player_1

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, I changed my approach, I think i was complicating things :) See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out. Changed my approach.

Instead of the generate_username function I created a counter that counts up for each iteration (for each user) generated.

It's slightly out of context, but looks as following:

**For each participant created, add the game id and count starting from 1 and up**

```
    count = 0
    for player_url in game_urls:
        count = count + 1
        user = User.objects.create_user(username='Player'+str(game.id)+'_'+str(count), password="123456", first_name=player_url, last_name=game.id)
        user.save()
```

**This will result in users being generated looking as following**

Player155_1

Player155_2

...etc

I just used the first_name and last_name table rows for the data for now. It's probably better to rename the user rows or add one called Game_ID and Player_URL